# Ascending and Descending according to the column value

Tags: sql

I have a `EMPLOYEE` table with `EMP_ID`,`NAME` and `DEPARTMENT_ID`.

I want  to order all the record with  odd `DEPARTMENT_ID` as `ASC` and even `DEPARTMENT_ID` as `DESC`.

Can it be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CASE` in the `ORDER BY`, change the sign accordingly:

```
...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN DEPARTMENT_ID  % 2 = 0
         THEN -DEPARTMENT_ID   
         ELSE  DEPARTMENT_ID END ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Makes two queries, first one filters odds, second pairs. Order by as you wish and then Union queries.

```
SELECT e.* FROM (SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE MOD(DEPARTMENT_ID, 2) = 1
ORDER BY DEPARTMENT_ID ASC) e
UNION ALL
SELECT e1.* FROM (SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE MOD(DEPARTMENT_ID, 2) = 0
ORDER BY DEPARTMENT_ID DESC) e1
```

Comment: I'm using oracle 11g. I it this code won't work.(after replacing '%' by mod())

Comment: Well, I don't have knowledges to answer for another database than mysql but you get the idea no? two separate queries that you unite.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
ORDER BY CASE WHEN DEPARTMENT_ID % 2 = 1 then 1 else 2 end,DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Comment: Orders both ascending, just splits them into two groups. Odd should be ASC and even should be DESC.